Rotating labels on lower half of pie chart
I am using Chart.js to generate a pie chart.
I want to rotate the labels on the lower half of the pie chart.
Here is my current code to generate the pie chart:


$(document).ready(
  function() {
    var data = {
      datasets: [{
        data: [125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125],
        backgroundColor: ["#FE4D42","#FFD405","#58E152","#00D59F","#8B7DFF","#E85FED","#F71663","#4F94FF"]
      }],
      labels: [
            "Arts and Creativity",
            "Careers and Employment",
            "Communities and Social",
            "Culture and Heritage",
            "Learning and Skills",
            "Personal Finance",
            "Self-Environment",
            "Wellbeing"
      ]
    };
      
    var labels_url = {
      "Arts and Creativity" : "arts-and-creativity",
      "Careers and Employment" : "careers-and-employment",
      "Communities and Social" : "communities-and-social",
      "Culture and Heritage" : "culture-and-heritage",
      "Wellbeing" : "health",
      "Learning and Skills" : "learning-and-skills",
      "Personal Finance" : "personal-finance",
      "Self-Environment" : "self-environment"
    };
    
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx,{
      type: 'pie',
      data: data,
      options: {
        legend: {
            display: false, 
        },
        plugins: {
          labels: {
            render: 'label',
            arc: true,
            fontColor:["#FF7805","#0854A3","#14A400","#048A7D","#502788","#F200F2","#FF0068","#000962"],
            fontSize: 18,
            position: 'outside'
          }
        }
      }
    });

    canvas.onclick = function(evt) {
      var activePoints = myNewChart.getElementsAtEvent(evt);
      if (activePoints[0]) {
        var chartData = activePoints[0]['_chart'].config.data;
        var idx = activePoints[0]['_index'];

        var label = chartData.labels[idx];
        var value = chartData.datasets[0].data[idx];

        var url = "https://www.maximiseme.co.uk/" + labels_url[label];
        //alert(url);
        console.log(url);
        window.location.href = url;
      }
    };
  }
);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/emn178/chartjs-plugin-labels/src/chartjs-plugin-labels.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>



I want to rotate the following labels to 180 degrees for better readability: Communities and Social, Culture and Heritage, Learning and Skills, Personal Finance.

A good and easy answer is that what you want to achieve is not possible with the libraries you are using. The labels are drawn by the chartjs-plugin-labels, which doesn't have a way to change the sense in which the text is rendered, it always renders the labels in a clockwise sense. It is also not under active development, the latest version is from 6 years ago.
But since the post contains a good minimal reproducible example, I thought
to write a hacky solution through a plugin that patches the existing code in the chartjs-plugin-labels. Alternatively, one could consider forking the plugin repository and adding a similar piece of code in a more straightforward manner.
This patch adds a new option to plugins.labels named reverse. If missing, reverse is false for all elements. It is similar to fontColor, indexable and scriptable. If an arc element has its reverse: true option, its label will be drawn in a counter-clockwise sense, otherwise it is drawn as usual, in a clockwise sense.
There's no need for further explanations, one can understand the details from the code itself.


var pluginLabelsExtension = {
    afterDatasetsUpdate(chart){
        if(chart._labels && chart._labels.length > 0){
            this._installLabelPatch(chart._labels[0].constructor);
        }
    },

    _installLabelPatch(Label){
        if(Label.prototype._patched){
            return;
        }
        Label.prototype._patched = true;
        const _getFontColor = Label.prototype.getFontColor,
            _renderArcLabel = Label.prototype.renderArcLabel;

        // use getFontColor to also get the `reverse` option for this element; save in element._view
        Label.prototype.getFontColor = function(dataset, element, index){
            var fontColor = _getFontColor.call(this, dataset, element, index);
            var reverse = false,
                optionReverse = this.options.reverse;
            if(typeof optionReverse === typeof true){
                reverse = optionReverse;
            }
            else if(typeof optionReverse === 'function'){
                reverse = optionReverse({
                    label: this.chart.config.data.labels[index],
                    value: dataset.data[index],
                    percentage: this.getPercentage(dataset, element, index),
                    backgroundColor: dataset.backgroundColor[index],
                    dataset: dataset,
                    index: index
                });
            }
            else if(Array.isArray(optionReverse)){
                reverse = optionReverse[index];
            }
            element._view.reverse = reverse;
            return fontColor;
        }

        Label.prototype.renderArcLabel = function(label, renderInfo){
            if(renderInfo.view.reverse && typeof label === 'string'){
                var ctx = this.ctx, radius = renderInfo.radius, view = renderInfo.view;
                var deltaToCenterFromEnd = renderInfo.startAngle - view.startAngle - Math.PI / 2;
                ctx.save();
                ctx.translate(view.x, view.y);
                ctx.rotate(renderInfo.endAngle - deltaToCenterFromEnd);
                ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
                ctx.textAlign = 'left';
                var lines = label.split('\n'), max = 0, widths = [], offset = 0;
                if(this.options.position === 'border'){
                    offset = (lines.length - 1) * this.options.fontSize / 2;
                }
                for(var j = 0; j < lines.length; ++j){
                    var mertrics = ctx.measureText(lines[j]);
                    if(mertrics.width > max){
                        max = mertrics.width;
                    }
                    widths.push(mertrics.width);
                }
                for(var j = 0; j < lines.length; ++j){
                    var line = lines[j];
                    var y = (lines.length - 1 - j) * -this.options.fontSize + offset;
                    ctx.save();
                    var padding = (max - widths[j]) / 2;
                    ctx.rotate(padding / radius);////
                    for(var i = 0; i < line.length; i++){
                        var char = line.charAt(i);
                        mertrics = ctx.measureText(char);
                        ctx.save();
                        ctx.translate(0, -1 * radius);
                        ctx.rotate(Math.PI);
                        ctx.fillText(char, 0, y);
                        ctx.restore();
                        ctx.rotate(-mertrics.width / radius);
                    }
                    ctx.restore();
                }
                ctx.restore();
            }
            else{
                _renderArcLabel.call(this, label, renderInfo)
            }
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(
    function() {
        var data = {
            datasets: [{
                data: [125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125],
                backgroundColor: ["#FE4D42","#FFD405","#58E152","#00D59F","#8B7DFF","#E85FED","#F71663","#4F94FF"]
            }],
            labels: [
                "Arts and Creativity",
                "Careers and Employment",
                "Communities and Social",
                "Culture and Heritage",
                "Learning and Skills",
                "Personal Finance",
                "Self-Environment",
                "Wellbeing"
            ]//.map(s => s.split(/[ \-]/)[0])
        };

        var labels_url = {
            "Arts and Creativity" : "arts-and-creativity",
            "Careers and Employment" : "careers-and-employment",
            "Communities and Social" : "communities-and-social",
            "Culture and Heritage" : "culture-and-heritage",
            "Wellbeing" : "health",
            "Learning and Skills" : "learning-and-skills",
            "Personal Finance" : "personal-finance",
            "Self-Environment" : "self-environment"
        };

        var canvas = document.getElementById("myChart");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx,{
            type: 'pie',
            data: data,
            options: {
                legend: {
                    display: false,
                },
                //animation: false,
                plugins: {
                    labels: {
                        render: 'label',
                        arc: true,
                        fontColor:["#FF7805","#0854A3","#14A400","#048A7D","#502788","#F200F2","#FF0068","#000962"],
                        reverse: [false, false, true, true, true, true, false, false],
                        fontSize: 18,
                        position: 'outside'
                    }
                }
            },
            plugins:[
                pluginLabelsExtension
            ]
        });

        canvas.onclick = function(evt) {
            var activePoints = myNewChart.getElementsAtEvent(evt);
            if (activePoints[0]) {
                var chartData = activePoints[0]['_chart'].config.data;
                var idx = activePoints[0]['_index'];

                var label = chartData.labels[idx];
                var value = chartData.datasets[0].data[idx];

                var url = "https://www.maximiseme.co.uk/" + labels_url[label];
                //alert(url);
                console.log(url);
                window.location.href = url;
            }
        };
    }
);
<canvas id="myChart" style="width: 1000px; height: 1000px"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/emn178/chartjs-plugin-labels/src/chartjs-plugin-labels.js"></script>




Thank you for your help. I have one more question—could you please look into it?
On mobile screens, the labels are overlapping. How can I resolve this issue within the same code?

That's really a very different problem; but there might be some solutions for that out here - what exactly do you want to happen when labels are overlapping? Do you want the labels to be cut where they overlap outside their zone?

I want the labels to be readable on mobile screens.

If the radius of the pie chart is smaller than approx 1000px, the labels will overlap because the text of the labels is rather long. This will happen with or without the reverse code you asked for in this question. I recommend you ask another question, but it has to be a technical question here on stackoverflow, you have to show what approach you used and what you have tried.
